# json_decode not printing object price_usd

Tags: json, decode

```html
<?php

      
   $url = file_get_contents("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin-cash/");
   $array = json_decode($url,TRUE);
   // print_r($array);
      $rate['price_usd'] =  $array->{"bitcoin-cash"}->{"price_usd"};
      $rate = $rate['price_usd'];

?>



      <center><font color="black">Rate: 1 <font color="green">BCH/BitCoin Cash</font> = <?=$rate?> USD</font></center>
```

Hello the problem is the json_decode its not printing object price_usd 
anyone know how to print just the object price_usd

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do `var_dump($array)` you can see the exact structure of it. Your current way of trying to get it doesn't make much sense.

The JSON from the API is this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "bitcoin-cash", 
        "name": "Bitcoin Cash", 
        "symbol": "BCH", 
        "rank": "3", 
        "price_usd": "3205.57", 
        "price_btc": "0.208515", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "4509330000.0", 
        "market_cap_usd": "54073197615.0", 
        "available_supply": "16868513.0", 
        "total_supply": "16868513.0", 
        "max_supply": "21000000.0", 
        "percent_change_1h": "-0.83", 
        "percent_change_24h": "-17.54", 
        "percent_change_7d": "71.22", 
        "last_updated": "1513885472"
    }
]
```

...and after converting it to an assoc array (by passing `true` to `json_decode()` as its 2nd param, fetching the rate should be done as:

`$array[0]['price_usd']`

Comment: Can you please complete the code its printing to me Array not the object price

Comment: God Bless you man , i fixed it 
 $rate = $array[0]['price_usd'];